# how to see simulator while running test cases on bitrise

Tags: detox, bitrise

Is it possible to see simulator while running test cases on bitrise . I am running detox test cases using bitrise as CI. I am not sure how it works therefore I am not at any idea of initiating the simulator on cloud and visible to user.

App platform : React Native 
OS : iOS 
Testing Framework : Detox / wix 
CI Tool : bitrise

Answer (score 1):

Remote access is now built into bitrise.io directly, no need to add any step: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/remote-access/
It supports both SSH and VNC connection for Mac VMs (VNC is the protocol used by the macOS built in "Screen Sharing" app but of course you can find clients on other operating systems) so you can screen share into the macOS build VM (for Linux build VMs only SSH is supported at the moment).

---

I'll leave the original answer here as that still works:

There's a semi-official, ngrok based solution, using the https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-remote-access-macos-ngrok bitrise step. You can find a setup & usage guide at: https://gist.github.com/viktorbenei/c6d4fe1e68de739dbb5f4f15de76b9db

A built in solution is also planned, in the meantime using `ngrok` (which this unofficial step uses) or a similar tool can provide a solution.